# Multiprocessing pool inner module error python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This error occurs in the multiprocessing library but I do not know what causes it or how to fix it.

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 576, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 256, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\exceptions.py", line 41, in __init__
    CompatJSONDecodeError.__init__(self, *args)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'doc' and 'pos'
```

Comment: It's an error in your code, not multiprocessing. Edit the question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Would be helpful to include some of your code. It is also possible that this is a JSON decoding error - do you have some JSON as input somewhere, which you can validate (with a validator)?

Answer (score 1):

The bug was in my code, the multiprocessing library didn't know how to properly handle the error. The error was caused by my request response with a 524 error caused by a block by cloudfare.